# Bundle an application inside IzPack

Tags: java, installation, bundle, inno-setup, izpack

I have a software that needs a config.xml file during the installation.

What we do now is to zip the "software.exe" with the "config.xml" and we give that to our customers. They un-zip and launch the software.

We would like to remove the un-zip part and bundle the "software.exe" and the "config.xml" so that we produce a software2.exe that will simply launch the software.exe.

The difficult part is that the zipping operation is taking place during server installation with IzPack.

So is there a way, during IzPack installation, to produce another "pack" from the file I specified? I wanted to use InnoSetup but I'm not sure I can use that external program inside IzPack..

Comment: Why do you want to combine the IzPack with Inno Setup? *"during IzPack installation, to produce another "pack" from the file I specified?"* - What does that mean?

Comment: My "software.exe" is produced by InnoSetup. 
My server installer is produced by IzPack. I want, during the server's installation, to create a bundle containing my "software.exe" and my "config.xml".

Comment: How could we have known that? - So why don't you install the `config.xml` by the `software.exe`?

Comment: The "software.exe" is produced a long time ago. The "config.xml" is generated each time the server is installed because the customer can specified some parameters (at installation time). 

Thus we do not have these parameters when we produce the "software.exe"...

Comment: We do not now what the *"server"* is. So you want your "server" to produce the `software2.exe`, by combining the `software.exe` with generated `config.xml`, right? So what does your question have to do with Inno Setup?

Comment: My server is simply a IzPack installer. When ran, it does some thing, and among, it currently zip my "software.exe" and the "config.xml" file.

So during the IzPack installation process, I want to produce a bundle. So my question is, can I use "InnoSetup" which IS capable of producing "software2.exe" during that step?

But maybe I can also use IzPack inside IzPack installation? Or maybe I can use any other tools. I'm just suggesting things.

Comment: Is your server Windows server? If not, you will have problems running Windows Inno Setup compiler there.

Comment: The server can be installed on any machine since IzPack is Java, thus cross platform.. But I suggested InnoSetup but maybe IzPack can do it..